# What is process/reaper and why isn't it working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, scripting

When deploying my Rails app via Capistrano, the very last thing it tries to execute is this:

```
sudo -p 'sudo password: ' -u app /home/user/public_html/example.com/current/script/process/reaper
```

Then it throws this error:

```
failed: "sh -c \"sudo -p 'sudo password: ' -u app /home/user/public_html/example.com/current/script/process/reaper\"" on 123.456.789.012
```

The app still deploys and starts fine...but what does process/reaper do and what can I do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the Mongrel/Passenger epoch and before being build upon Rack, the only way to run a Rails application was using CGI or FGCI.
The script/reaper file was used to start/stop a Rails process.

By default, Capistrano tries to start a new Rails process running the reaper script.
You should customize the default behaviour.

Assuming you are running your Rails app using Passenger (mod_rails), install the following [Capistrano + Passenger (mod_rails)](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2008/12/capistrano-deploy-recipe-with-passenger-mod_rails-taste/) recipe and Capistrano will gracefully restart your Passenger instance on deploy.

Comment: So can I just delete the script/process directory? I've already got my app deploying fine...just need to kill of that error. If that recipe is the only way to do it, cool. But just wondering if it's even easier to do.

Comment: Yes, you can. In fact, if you create a new Rails 2.3 project, that file won't be created.

Answer (score 3):

Using rails 2.3 I added this to my `config/deploy.rb`

```
deploy.task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
end
```

That stopped the reaper error and properly restarted passenger.